# double integral of $\sin \frac{y}{x+y}$

Tags: integration

> Calculate $$\iint \sin \left(\frac{y}{x+y}\right)dxdy$$
>   over the region surrounded by lines: $x+y=1$, $x=0$ and $y=0$

Since it seems difficult to directly calculate, I think substitution would work but how to choose the new variables? When I chose $u=\frac{y}{x+y}$, things become even more complex for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose the substitution $(x,y) \mapsto (u,v)= (x+y,y)$. In terms of the new variables, the integration boundaries are $0\leq u \leq 1$ and $0\leq v \leq u$. The Jacobian of the variable transform is one so, we have

$$\int_{\substack{0\leq x,y \leq 1\\
  0\leq x+ y \leq 1}} \!\! dx\,dy \sin(y/(x+y)) = \int_0^1 du \int_0^u dv
\sin(v/u) =  \int_0^1du\,u (1-\cos 1) =\tfrac12(1-\cos1).$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Use the jacobian  and map the region with new variables, $u$ and $v$, in order to make integrating easier.

Comment: Would you please tell more about what $u$ and $v$ should be to make the new function more convenient to solve?

Comment: @zgzhen I would use $u = x+y$ and $v = y$

Comment: @zgzhen or just look at Fabian's answer